# JSON structure for message payload

Tags: json

I am sending a message to a third party and the payload looks like as below:

```
{
  "keys": {
    "salesCaseId": 1000449
  },
  "attributes": {
    "assetDeliveryDetails": {
      "registrationNumber": "PXS3388",
      "vinNumber": "DW1265",
      "deliveryDate": "16-04-2020"
    }
  }
}
```

"Keys" and "attributes" are common for all the messages between us.

Question: Because I have only one nested JSON inside `attributes` which is `assetDeliveryDetails` is it necessary to have this nested JSON property? or I can have the other 3 attributes one level higher as below :

```
{
  "keys": {
    "salesCaseId": 1000449
  },
  "attributes": {
    "assetRegistrationNumber": "PXS3388",
    "assetVinNumber": "DW1265",
    "assetDeliveryDate": "16-04-2020"
  }
}
```

Does it makes sense to group because I can logically group them together or is it an overhead because I need to create equivalent DTO classes as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking you want any data structure (whether that's JSON, XML, an Object model, etc.) to be as simple as possible to fulfill your requirements. If the second model (i.e. without `assetDeliveryDetails`) fulfills your requirements then I recommend you go with that. Unnecessary complexity is not desirable as it will be more difficult to understand and take more resources to parse..